# join table with another joined table

Tags: database-design

So I have an entity called order with set of materials within it. which is another entity just like in the following code.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "order_material", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "material_id"))
private Set<Material> Materials;
```

I want to add to the order entity another quantity field but it should be per material.  So we have a quantity per material per order. I am kind of confused how to do. it in terms of database.

I thought of the following:

1- create another table for order_material_quantity and connect it with order.

2- I thought of this but I am not sure if it's possible: is it possible to jointable with  the joined table we have order_material?

3- any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question about in database design not about spring-boot and hibernate.
I recommend you that break down your order table in two table: order and order_detail.

like this:

```
@Table("order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column("order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    @Column("creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column("user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column("customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_detail", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_detail_id"))
    private Set<OrderDetail> orderDetails;

}
```

and:

```
@Table("order_detail")
public class OrderDetail {

    @Id
    @Column("order_detail_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false,updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Order order;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "material_id", nullable = false,updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Material material;

    @Column("quantity")
    private Long quantity;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I think this cleared the vision to me